# How to handle game scores of last week in MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

I have a GAME_SCORES table in my MySQL DB
Which is having simple columns like this

```
UserID TotalScore
```

The table is storing the total score done by that user.
I would need to alter the above Table or create the new one so that I can handle the LastWeek 
and ThisWeek and TotalScore aswell.so I may need to change the above table to below

```
UserID TotalScore ThisWeekScore LastWeekScore
```

I would like to know the Best and Most efficient way to handle this.

Please let me know guys I am new to MySQL.

Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to just store the date when this score was gained? maybe start/end date? this way you can then count weeks, months, anything.

Comment: Thanks for your thought. Yes, I can store the date, But what I need is the Score associated with the Date, which i can get, but, I also need the score associated only this week and only last week etc., Any Idea How can we handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create two tables:

```
UserID
```

and

```
Scores
```

where Scores table has **score**, **date**, and **user_id** field.

I would then get ThisWeekScore using

```
SELECT * FROM UserID JOIN Scores ON UserId.id = Scores.user_id WHERE Scores.date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY AND Scores.date < curdate()
```

And get LastWeekScore using similar technique.

Comment: Thanks! Ismail,Its great idea!, I ll accept the answer, but still looking for a far better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Make it clear, you have scores from different game or something, and you add them up into one column (totalScore)? If yes, then you need to have all the scores saved seperately in another table and have totalScore, thisWeekScore, lastWeekScore in this new table.

Comment: Hi, I need to handle scores from only one Game, and yes I am adding up to the total score, Ismail also had the same thought of having two separate tables for Scores and Users, as I said, I am still looking for most powerful technique to handle this.

Comment: Yes, seperate table will help you later on enhancing it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the task is. But it seems that a bit different database structure should fit more.

```
    +-----------+         +------------+
    | User      |         | Score      |
    +-----------+ 1     ∞ +------------+
    | id        | ------- | user_id    |
    | name      |         | score      |
    | ...       |         | created_at |
    +-----------+         +------------+
```

Thus You will be able to fetch latest scores, this week best score, last week score or any other.

Or if You just want to add two columns use  [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: Hey Bender! Thank you!, You also have correct answer!. You also suggested to have Alter Table. Can you let me know, what is the best way... I mean Altering the existing table, or having the two tables. I might get lots of records in future.

Comment: I think separate tables is a better solution in perspective. Because adding two columns will not allow you to keep any history. You will only be able to fetch this week score, last week score. 

And if in future You want to get the total best score, or the score two weeks ago or just see the history - You won't be able to do that.